# typescript build option in visual studio 2015

Tags: typescript

I am currently using the 2.1 version of the typescript, but I am using ECMAScript6 as the build option because of the asynchronous (Promise) function.

However, the website you are currently developing must also be present in the IE version, which causes errors when building **ECMAScript 6**.
One example is that the way you build [class] is different.

**ECMAScript 5** build method:

```
var Preview = (function () {
function Preview() {
    alert(333);
}
return Preview;}());
```

**ECMAScript 6** build method:

```
class Preview {
    constructor() {
        alert(333);
    }
}
```

IE does not recognize **ECMAScript 6** built scripts.

What I want is to build certain TS files with **ECMAScript 6** and build the rest with **ECMAScript 5**.

I only want to build a specific page on Chrome with **ECMAScript 6**, but I want to know if this is possible by modifying the project file. Please suggest a solution.

The reason I need to use **ECMAScript 6** is because I need to use the [Promise]class because of callback processing.

I use the visualstudio tool, so the **tsconfig** file is

My current tool is VS2015. I am using 4 versions of Asp.Net.

Comment: Shwo us your tsconfig.json file

Comment: You will need two build steps, one build most code in es5, and the other on build that code in es6.

On the other hand, I don't see why do you need to do this. `async` / `await` can transpile and work in es5.